# How to Mock a Python library function?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Let's say I have a Person class:

```
from operator import add
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age: int):
        self.age = age

    @property
    def age_in_a_decade(self):
        res = add(10, self.age)
        return res
```

And I want to test the 'add' function is called.

```
class PersonTests(TestCase):
    @patch('operator.add')
    def test_age_in_a_decade(self, mock_add) -> None:
        test_person = Person(age=51)
        mock_add.return_value = 61
        age_10 = self.test_person.age_in_a_decade
        self.assertEqual(age_10, 61)
        mock_add.assert_called_once_with(10, 51)
```

This raise AssertionError 'add' is not called.

I know this will be fixed if I change the Person class to

```
import operator

class Person:
    @property
    def age_in_a_decade(self):
        res = operator.add(10, self.age)
        return res
```

Is there any way to leave the Person class as is and fix the test only?

Comment: You need to patch `add` in the namespace of the module under test, not the namespace of `operator`.  You don't show how you import the module under test, but if you do `from person import Person`, do `@patch(person.add)`.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to check that the function is called, as opposed to checking that your `age_in_a_decade` method produces the right result?